# Has it occured to you that a GitLab repository that had deletion pending was not deleted after deadline passed?

Tags: gitlab

According to new GitLab rules, if you delete a repo, this deletion is executed with some delay ( one week ), the deletion deadline is shown in the repo head ( you can revert this decision up to the deadline ).

**My repo was to be deleted on 18th February. Now it is 19th February and the repo is still there, and still says it will be deleted on 18th February. ( An other repo of mine that had deletion pending on 18th February, was deleted in due course. ) Is this a common thing? Has this happened to you?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if it is a [timezone issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/timezone.html), meaning if it is supposed to be deleted at an UTC hour which would mean:

- it is still the 18th
- even though it is already 19th in your zone

If not, check the logs for any error message regarding that repository.

The [OP sbtpr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5629360/sbtpr) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304864/has-it-occured-to-you-that-a-gitlab-repository-that-had-deletion-pending-was-not/60314408#comment106806298_60314408):

> I waited patiently, out of curiosity, to see what happens, and voila, after almost an other week passed, on 24th February, my repo was deleted.
> So I'd better factor in that with GitLab deleting a repo may take 2 weeks.

---

Note that a pending deletion status can also be canceled.

See [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#users-can-recover-projects-pending-deletion) (March 2022)

> ### Users can recover projects pending deletion
>
> In previous versions of GitLab, only Administrators could see projects that were pending deletion.
>
> With GitLab 14.9, all users can now view the **Pending deletion** tab.
> Project and group owners can view and recover projects that were accidentally deleted and
> have not yet been permanently removed from disk. This means users can recover their own accidentally deleted projects without needing to direct all recovery requests to an Administrator.
>
> To see the tab, on the top bar, select **Menu > Projects > Pending deletion**.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_9/compliance-pending-deletion-tab.png -- Users can recover projects pending deletion]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#projects-pending-deletion) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7568).

Comment: It cannot be a timezone issue, because it is now the 20th and the repo is still there. Exactly what log should I check? I cannot find any repo related log, other than Overview / Activity, which records my pushes.

Comment: @sbtpr What kind of GitLab installation do you have on your server? Or is it gitlab.com?

Comment: It is gitlab.com.

Comment: @sbtpr Then opening an issue would be the next step: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues

Comment: Before opening any git issue, I waited patiently, out of curiosity, to see what happens, and voila, after almost an other week passed, on 24th February, my repo was deleted. So I'd better factor in that with GitLab deleting a repo may take 2 weeks.

Comment: @sbtpr That is strange. They must have a large backlog queue to process...

Comment: [Delayed project deletion](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#delayed-project-deletion "Manage projects | GitLab") is available in the *Premium* and *Ultimate* tiers. So you will not observe this for own projects if you use the free account. Nevertheless, the *Pending deletion* tab is available, is it also for projects that you observe or star?

Comment: @Wolf Are you asking the OP sbtpr? If yes, you need a `@sbtpr` in your message for sbtpr to be notified.

Comment: No, I'm sorry for causing confusion by adding more details and asking this question. The question was directed at you because I assumed you had the relevant expertise: Does this tab also show other people's projects that are in delayed deletion? I tried to find this detail documented, but without success so far. Maybe it's just a glitch that I see the *Pending deletion* tab at all since I'm using the *Free Plan*.

Comment: @Wolf OK. I wouldn't be able to check that right now (I do not manage a GitLab instance these days).

Comment: Thanks for your time: I know that I don't see the tab on an instance run on my company. But I see it in the `github.com` instance where I have a free account.

Comment: @Wolf Strange, that would be a good question to [their support](https://about.gitlab.com/support/).

Comment: @VonC I now carefully read what is written in that tab (maybe that's changed in the last days): * No projects pending deletion found

Projects that are pending deletion that **you have access to** are listed here.* (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Wolf OK, so no "other people's projects".

Comment: I think the tab is visible to people with free accounts, because they might have gotten access to other people's projects (run by paying users).